# How to get "save actions" code format to ignore comments

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I generally like intellij's "save actions" reformatting, but it compacts comments that I have added some formatting to (e.g. a list of items).

How can I tell the "Save actions" plugin to not format comments while it reformats proper code?